# Objective C - Singleton not persisting data after App restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I make a singleton like this:

```
+ (CurrentUser *)sharedInstance {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

It has a property called:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *profilePicData;
```

I save an image like this:

```
[[CurrentUser sharedInstance] setProfilePicData:profilePictureData];
```

I load the image like this:

```
if ([[CurrentUser sharedInstance]profilePicData]) {

    self.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[CurrentUser sharedInstance]profilePicData]];
}
```

The image shows up and everything is good, but when I restart the app and go to the same view controllers that contain this same code, the image no longer appears in the `UIImageView`. This leads me to believe the singleton is not persisting.

How do I persist the data across app restarts with a singleton object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singleton instance is only alive while the app is running. You need to save `profilePictureData` to a file when it is set and then load it when the singleton gets created, once the app is run again.

For writing you can use `[profilePicData writeToURL:atomically:]`

Then in your singleton's initializer you should load this file into `profilePicData` again with  `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`

The URL used for writing must be the same you use for loading, and must be within your app's sandbox.

See [NSData's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/)